# overriding jQuery.find() function to provide extra functionality

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to override jQuery.find to override extra functionality. I have used the idea discussed on Ben Nadel's blog to do so ( http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1624-Ask-Ben-Overriding-Core-jQuery-Methods.htm ) but for some reason it doesn't work for $.find(), this is my code

```
        (function () {
        // Store a reference to the original remove method.
        var originalFindFunction = jQuery.find;

        // Define overriding method.
        jQuery.find = function () {
            // Log that we are calling the overridden function.
            Console.log("------> Find method called");

            // then execute the original method
            var results = originalFindFunction.apply(this, arguments);
            return results;
        };
    })();
```

do you have an idea what's wrong, or how can I override a jquery function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demonstration in your reference uses a function from `.fn.`

```
jQuery.fn.remove
```

Where you're overriding a function on

```
jQuery.find
```

Overriding functions on this level have different meaning for `this`.
When you're working on `.fn.` - the this is the returned query result, which are "mixed in" to any query result.

Here, the `this` will be the root object itself, and the usage by it is different. These are functions or utility functions that are invoked "statically".

Comment: overriding jquery.fn instead solved the problem. Thanks for the extra explanation.

Comment: I wasn't sure about what you're trying to do - so I tried to ley out both alternatives and their meanings :)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for overriding/hooking into `jQuery.fn.find` not `jQuery.find`.

---

```
(function () {
    // Store a reference to the original remove method.
    var originalFindFunction = jQuery.fn.find;

    // Define overriding method.
    jQuery.fn.find = function () {
        // Log that we are calling the overridden function.
        Console.log("------> Find method called");

        // then execute the original method
        var results = originalFindFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        return results;
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't see any fault in your code. It's true the example uses the jQuery prototype("fn"), however you can manipulate $.find as well. I've basically copied the same code you provided in the following example:

```
var oldFind = $.find;

$.find = function() {
    console.log("something new.");

    console.log(oldFind.apply(this, arguments));
};

$.find("div");
```

Realize, you may be executing this in a specific way. Above you have:

```
(function() {...})();
```

This makes the code within the first parens, self-executing(correct me if I'm wrong here), which may not have the intent desired if you call the contained code outside this function. A working example of the snippet above is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nuPLV/